# WCF and ASP.NET Compatibility Mode with https

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, ssl

Can I use https and ssl when a wcf is running in compatibility mode?

Can I use transport security?

Can I use UserNameOverTransport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To all your question I reply yes as I just did it in my project. You basically set your WCF in asp.net compatibility mode, with transport security and it works like a charm ...

BUT (there is always a but)

The only issue I haven't been able to solve : It seems that WCF is not keeping the session while in HTTPS ... And it got me crazy.

Please, if there is someone out there that can tell me how to keep my Session between WCF (asp.net compatibility mode) calls in HTTPS, I would really appreciate !

Comment: Regarding the session in HTTPS, it appears to be a bug : be sure you add <authentication mode="None"/> in <sytem.web> if trying to do a principalPermission demand()

Comment: I had the same problem until I switched from wsHttpBinding to wsHttpContextBinding.  This mysteriously works, but it doesn't keep track of any authentication such as Membership.